# Setting up an FTP share folder access from remote desktop

Tags: iis, ftp

Here is the setup: I have a computer running windows 7 where i connect to a remote desktop. I want to set up a shared folder using FTP so i can copy files from the remote desktop to my local machine. I've created the shared folder using the ISS tool. I set it up so that no credentials are needed (allowed access to all users and anonymous users). I tested it with other computers in the network and it works. 
To access the file i want to use NET USE but when i try it from the remote desktop i get asked for a password.

How do I add the user from the remote desktop or what password and username is it expecting.

I am not the admin on the remote desktop, only on the local machine.

I can view the contents from the shared folder if i type ftp://3.xx.xx.x/   . This works on the remote desktop as well.

Please help.... im loosing my mind!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using Active mode from the FTP client. Worked for me, I couldn't even get a directory listing before.